# Как вставить данные из mysql в html

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть сайт который написан на чистом html, css, js и бекенд на Node js, express. Не знаю как правильно получить и вставить значения в html.

Это как я сделал работу с бд

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    database: "findyourhustle",
    password: "Atmp123key"
});
```

и встака данных через innerHTML но мне сказали что это замедляет работу приложения, поэтому рассматриваю другие варианты.

Заранее спасибо.

также nodejs ругается на строку  programmer = document.querySelectorAll, "ReferenceError: document is not defined
"

```
connection.query('SELECT unit_name FROM units', function (error, results) {
    if (error) throw error;
    returnValue(results);
});

let programmer, trading, car_sales, solar_panels, real_estate;

function returnValue(value) {
    programmer = document.querySelectorAll(".programmer .color-line");
}
```

Comment: А какой ответ вы ожидаете? в чем проблема то? приведите примеры кода с которым у вас проблемы

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RgHi5n7wYeU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не могу писать комментарий, поэтому отвечу тут.

С английским дружишь? Вот ссылка на подробный референс по твоей проблеме: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718091/alternative-for-innerhtml

Несколько выводов:
1) Синтаксис `innerHTML` значительно проще
2) Не всегда innerHTML медленнее альтернатив - есть ссылка на бенчмарки

Comment: Отличная статья, вопрос когда хочу получить элемент document.querySelectorAll, выбивает ошибку документ не найден, как указать страницу в mpa?

Comment: Что такое mpa? Без кода тяжело понять в чем проблема. Можешь хотя бы кусок вставить, на который ругается?

Comment: добавил в конце описание, и mpa это multi page application

Comment: Ты не можешь в ноде использовать `document.querySelectorAll`, т.к. это браузерный АПИ и такое можно использовать только на клиенте (в браузере). Опиши просто словами, что ты хочешь сделать? Что-то с клиента положить в базу?

Comment: вытянуть из бд значение и вставить в html пустой тег

Comment: Тогда тебе надо сделать API к этим данным в бд и на клиенте (html) брать их через этот API. У тебя сейчас как-то данные из БД уже приходят в html? Сделай также, если да